# Optimal Clusters Formula: Finding Equivalent Using NbClust

Tags: r, matrix, cluster-analysis, correlation, hierarchical-clustering

I have two variables that I calculated from Matrix B:

1) The Correlation Matrix `cor(B)`

2) The Hierarchical Cluster of the Dissimilarity Matrix from the Correlation Matrix

I then used the `clustConfigurations` function to calculate the "elbow graph" to determine the optimal amount of clusters.

See Code Below:

```
library(NetCluster)

B = matrix( 
      c(2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1,
        0, 1, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 2,
        1, 0, 1, 4, 0, 0, 2,
        0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 2,
        0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1,
        1, 0, 2, 2, 2, 1, 8), 
  nrow=7, 
  ncol=7) 
  colnames(B) = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")
  rownames(B) = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G") 
B

  A B C D E F G
A 2 0 0 1 0 0 1
B 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
C 0 0 3 1 0 0 2
D 1 0 1 4 0 0 2
E 0 2 0 0 4 0 2
F 0 1 0 0 0 2 1
G 1 0 2 2 2 1 8

Correlation_Matrix <- cor(B)
dissimilarity <- 1 - Correlation_Matrix
Correlation_Matrix_dist <- as.dist(dissimilarity)
Correlation_Matrix_dist
HClust_Correlation_Matrix <- hclust(Correlation_Matrix_dist)
clustered_observed_cors = vector()
num_vertices <- ncol(B)
clustered_observed_cors1 <-clustConfigurations(num_vertices,HClust_Correlation_Matrix,Correlation_Matrix)
```

When I tried doing this with a larger matrix specifically 1213 x 1213, the matrix was too large to run this script so I decided to use another package called `NbClust`.

Documentation:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/NbClust/NbClust.pdf

My goal was to recreate the process above with this new package but I'm not sure whether or not the below code is equivalent to above:

```
library(NbClust)

nbclustering<-NbClust(diss = Correlation_Matrix_dist, 
distance = NULL, 
min.nc=2, 
max.nc=20, 
method = "complete", 
index = "dunn")

This would give you the optimal amount of clusters:
nbclustering$Best.nc
```

Is the above code equivalent to my original code and if not, what change do I need to make?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you want to achieve, in the end? Is it clustering your variables? Your question may not be the one you want an answer about.

Comment: I want to find the optimal amount of clusters and then revert back to the hierarchical cluster dendogram and make a cutoff based on my findings. I wouldn't use the dendogram per-say, I would just use the results. @YCR

Comment: I was using the Stanford R Labs as a reference and they mentioned to use the correlation matrix. This is ultimately for Social Network Analysis. The link is here: http://sna.stanford.edu/lab.php?l=6 The code for this begins on line 124.

Comment: When I tried testing out their code, my matrix was too large so I am trying to find an alternative for specifically line 196

Comment: Also, take that back, you can also find the which variables belong to what clusters by doing nbclustering$Best.partition. So I basically just need to know how to make the nbclust formula equivalent to the original code @YCR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NbClust` is a broader function than `hclust` with more focus on the metrics to assess the final number of clusters.

The default method for `hclust` is [`"complete"`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete-linkage_clustering).

It is the same method used with NbClust with the option: `method = "complete"`.

So it is correct to use the result of Nbclust to define the number of final cluster for the clustering obtained by the function `hclust`.

Comment: What about the indices, there are 4 options: frey, mcclain, cindex, sihouette, and dunn. Which one would give the same result as the original code?

Comment: The function `clustConfigurations` is not implemented in NbClust. But you can use the others metrics to asses non-graphically the optimal number of clusters for your problem.

Comment: Ok thanks, maybe I can just see out of the 5 indices, what the most popular one is and choose that. Think that is the best way to do this or do you have a different suggestion? @YCR

Comment: Weight the indices based on the question you want to answer and pick the indices which seems the most appropriate to your problem(generally, the majority of the indices are in a small fork, making the choice easy)